# Searching for a way to construct a multidimensional, multilayered, associative Array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, associative-array

So i am running into trouble while iterating through a string and inserting it's chars as index-arrays into a multidimensional,associative array. So basically a bunch of multidimensional arrays in multidimensional arrays in multidimensional arrays.....
That is a bit troublesome as i cant do it by hand. I need an automated way to do this with a bunch of strings. The following example will explain it a bit better i think:

```
//string i want to enter
$string = 'ADAM';
//array i want to end up with
$result = array
              (
                'A'=> array
                 (
                  'D'=>array
                   (
                    'A'=>array
                     (
                      'M'=>array
                        (
                          'result'=>'ADAM'
                        )
                     )
                   )
                 )
               )
```

my initial approach was just using if-conditions to insert the first Char as Array into the main-array like:

```
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++){
      if($i == 0){
       $array1[$word[$i]] = array();
      }
}
```

which works pretty well. But then i ran into my Problem: how do i keep track of the current point in the array? 
Following the if-check i would go for an else-statement that acts when $i is bigger than 0. But if i want to insert the next dimension of array, which would be 'D' in this case, i would need to select $array1['A'], for the next i would need $array1['A']['D'] etc. I wasn't able to find a way yet to do that. The strings i need to get into this array vary from 4-70 chars.
Each method i know of only changed the 2nd dimension so i ended up with:

```
$array1('A'=>array ('A' =>array()));
$array1('A'=>array ('D' =>array()));
$array1('A'=>array ('A' =>array()));
$array1('A'=>array ('M' =>array()));
```

or illegal offset-errors caused by the indexes being arrays themselves.
Maybe my approach here is not possible, but i still thought i might ask in case i missed something.

In a Later stage im looking to use the same array for all strings so i basically use the Chars as nodes.. if 'A' as first char already exists i would then skip that and insert the 2nd char of the next string into the 'A'-Array etc.

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: its fine dont worry. i Will try the recommended solutions out on Monday, a lot of good dieas for sure!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a recursive function for this.

```
function nest(string $str, int $i = 0) {
    return isset($str[$i]) ? [$str[$i] => nest($str, $i + 1)] : ['result' => $str];
}

$result = nest($string);
```

Comment: This is definitely the best way to do this. You might want to make a note about using `array_merge_recursive($result, nest($string2));` to add new words to the array.

Comment: @NigelRen I just think recursion is the most natural way to solve problems of generating results of arbitrary depth. To me when I look at this code, it's obvious that at the bottom you add the `result` element, then when you unroll the recursion you push the previous letter until you get back to the start. Having said that, it's definitely a personal preference and your and Omar's approach is perfectly valid - I just find it a lot harder to read that code and understand what is going on.

Comment: @NigelRen you're right about the overhead of recursion but the overhead of adding new words to the array (as OP describes in their last paragraph) - for which I suggested using `array_merge_recursive` - will be the same for either method - unless you have a better way?

Comment: this works absolutly flawless and i understand whats happening here. Also @Nick thanks for the hint. i added the array_merge_recursive statement in a foreach loop with an array of strings and it works perfectly

Answer (score 1):

You can use references, so that as you go through the string you add the next character as the key to the array and then set this new entry as the add point for the next operation in the loop...

```
$string = 'ADAM';
$result = [];
$add = &$result;
for($i = 0; $i < strlen($string); $i++){
    $add = &$add[$string[$i]];
}
$add['result'] = $string;
print_r($result);
```

Just to show how adding multiple entries would work...

```
addEntry ( $result, "ADAM");
addEntry ( $result, "ALAN");
addEntry ( $result, "ADAME");

function addEntry ( &$result, string $newValue )  {
    for($i = 0; $i < strlen($newValue); $i++){
        $result = &$result[$newValue[$i]];
    }
    $result['result'] = $newValue;
}
```

results in...

```
Array
(
    [A] => Array
        (
            [D] => Array
                (
                    [A] => Array
                        (
                            [M] => Array
                                (
                                    [result] => ADAM
                                    [E] => Array
                                        (
                                            [result] => ADAME
                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            [L] => Array
                (
                    [A] => Array
                        (
                            [N] => Array
                                (
                                    [result] => ALAN
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Comment: ahhh i totally forgot about references. Makes sense like this, no wonder i got undefined index errors. Thats where my lack of experience shows sometimes hehe

Answer (score 1):

here is a solution for what you are trying to achieve. See a working solution [here](https://tehplayground.com/Z8PZsfSAM8Pm0e1a) with comments to explain it's working.

```
$val = 'ADAM';
$arr = [];
$keys = str_split($val);
$curr = &$arr;
foreach($keys as $key) {
    $curr = &$curr[$key];
}
$curr = ['result' => $val];

print_r($arr);
```

Comment: interesting solution. I didnt know about the str_split function.